# Is it possible to use Argon2 on Google App Engine Standard environment?

Tags: google-app-engine

I'm in the process of migrating an application to Google App Engine. If possible I want to use the standard environment. My application uses Argon2 to hash passwords. Neither on PHP 7.2, 7.3 nor 7.4 Argon2 is available with a basic app.yaml file.

app.yaml:

```yaml
runtime: php72|php73|php74
```

Is there any configuration I can adjust to get the support for Argon2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to use `Argon2` it is necessary to install 3rd party libraries that are not included in the php distributions (to install you do `sudo apt install argon2` ). Based on this information, the best solution for you would be to use Cloud Run[1].

Follow the tutorial in the Cloud Run Quickstart [2], taking into account that you have to edit your Dockerfile to make sure that Argon2 is installed.

[1] https://cloud.google.com/serverless-options

[2] https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/quickstarts/build-and-deploy#php